# I have used @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM CVT_CODE_INDEX") i am not able retrive value from DB..pls let me know

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM CVT_CODE_INDEX")
```

i am not able retrive value from DB..pls let me know

```
List<DropDownValues> dropdownDetailsList =  dropDownRepository.findAllValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't select *

You should select the columns in the order of your DropDownValues and if the names of the columns don't match the attribute names use aliases.

Example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT name AS name, age AS age FROM Person", nativeQuery = true)
List<PersonSummary> findAllProjectedNativeQuery();
```